Extract liftIO and runSql in separate function (Haskell)
I use Persist and Servant. I have the following definitions in one module:
-- Type alias for convenience
type DbAction m a = ReaderT SqlBackend m a

-- Run database queries with a connection pool
runSql :: DbAction (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO)) a -> ConnectionPool -> IO a
runSql = runSqlPersistMPool

Now, in my Servant API definition (different module), I have a bunch of these:
    postUser :: UserCreate -> Handler Text
    postUser user = liftIO $ flip runSql pool $ do
      storeUser user

    getUser :: PathUserId -> Handler (Maybe User)
    getUser uid = liftIO $ flip runSql pool $ do
      fetchUser $ extractUserId uid

I want to extract liftIO $ flip runSql pool $ ... in a function so I don't repeat it all over the file.
For some reason I am stuck here and can't figure it out :(
EDIT
Something I tried:
runDbAction :: SqlPersistT IO a -> Handler a
runDbAction action = liftIO $ flip runSql pool $ action

however, SqlPersistT exist only in Sqlite package, and I dont want to depend on it...
SOLUTION
I ended up using
    runDbAction :: SqlPersistM a -> Handler a
    runDbAction action = liftIO $ runSql action pool


What have you tried? How does it fail? If there's an error message, what does it say?

I tried multiple ways of extracting... it will be of no use of writing all my tries here; that would be just noise. I added one example of what I tried.

Why don't you want to depend on the sqlite package? Surely you're going to need to eventually if that's really the right type.

Surely you already do depend on it, if that's the type of the expression you're trying to extract?

@DanielWagner you are right, I just don't see how this particular piece of code is dependend on sqlite. There is ConnectionPool and SqlBackend, which are general. So if we have runSql, I believe we can replace it with something not depending on implementation...

Maybe runDbAction :: DbAction (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO)) a -> Handler a is the correct type for your definition? (BTW, I'd use runDbAction action = liftIO $ runSql action pool to define it. No need for flip there.)

Something like this can be written without depending on particularly specialized libraries:
runDbAction :: MonadIO m => r -> ReaderT r IO a -> m a
runDbAction r = liftIO . flip runReaderT r

We have the following specialized definitions:
type SqlPersistT = ReaderT SqlBackend
newtype Handler a
instance MonadIO Handler

which means that runDbAction can be used as if it had this type:
runDbAction :: SqlBackend -> SqlPersistT IO a -> Handler a

Of course, you can't bake pool into the definition without depending on the package that gives you SqlBackend.

(This answer assumes you are using persistent to provide SqlPersistT and servant-server to provide Handler.)

Thanx! After some sleep, I ended up with:
runDbAction :: SqlPersistM a -> Handler a
runDbAction action = liftIO $ runSql action pool
